# A searchable Prolog language description online

Tags: prolog, standards, iso-prolog

Is there a description of Prolog language (syntax and semantics) available online?

There are a lot of reference manuals for implementations. But neither of those is a language description. For example the SWI Prolog manual [states](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%271.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/swiprolog.html%27%29%29)

> This manual does not describe the full syntax and semantics of Prolog.

And [refers](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%271.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/swiprolog.html%27%29%29) to a set of books printed on paper, published in the nineteen eighties.
And to ISO standard which is for money and "should be available from my country's ISO representative" gibberish.

Comment: You could have a look at the GNU Prolog manual, there might be some implementation differences but GNU Prolog conforms to the ISO standard also: http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html

Comment: This is just another implementation manual. Does it specify the notation for octal integers? Does it discuss such nice details as what is a whitespace and where the whitespaces are mandatory? What does backslash at the end of the line do? etc

Comment: Googlng Prolog Syntax turned this up: http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/3.7.1/html/sicstus_45.html

Comment: @HunterMcMillen: This documentation is no longer current. You are referring to version 3 of SICStus. [Here is the current version of it, much closer to ISO](http://www.sics.se/sicstus/docs/latest4/html/sicstus.html/ref_002dsyn.html)

Comment: The whole chapter "4 The Prolog Language" seems very relevant. (Modulo the fact that this is probably shifted in favour of sicstus).

Comment: One more thing I was able to find that is tangentially relevant: [ISO Prolog: A summary of the draft proposed standard.](http://fsl.cs.uiuc.edu/images/9/9c/PrologStandard.pdf)

Answer (score 5):

The ISO standard is available for a very low price (currently USD <s>30</s> 60) [from the ANSI webstore](http://webstore.ansi.org/FindStandards.aspx?SearchString=INCITS/ISO/IEC%2013211-1-1995%20%28R2007%29&SearchOption=0&PageNum=0&SearchTermsArray=null%7CINCITS/ISO/IEC%2013211-1-1995%20%28R2007%29%7Cnull) as an INCITS document. Instructions to [get the original document](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/#access) for USD 30. There you also get the three corrigenda for free. See [iso-prolog tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iso-prolog/info) for all current documents. Here is a comprehensive [overview of all built-in predicates](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#status_quo) which includes Cor.1, Cor.2, and Cor.3.

If you want a printout version, the best is still to print above INCITS document yourself being aware that page 10 is missing (a page left intentionally blank) — otherwise subsequent odd pages are on the left side. The document is an A4 scan with two columns per page. The informal Annex A goes better in a separate binding.  Instead, add the three corrigenda!

Alternatively, [SAI](http://infostore.saiglobal.com/EMEA/results2.aspx?searchType=simple&publisher=All&keyword=prolog) sells hardcopies.

Comment: USD 30 is definitely better than CHF 238.

Comment: @WouterBeek: This answer will be of interest to you. Alternatively, you get all documents from your national member body. [Here is Cor.2](http://www.nen.nl/NEN-Shop-2/Standard/NENISOIEC-1321111995C22012-en.htm).

Comment: @false Thanks for pointing us to these documents! Too bad this question was considered off-topic. The new generation of Web and Open Source programmers is not used to buying these kinds of resources from standards bodies, but they definitely should. These docs contain a ton of info.

Comment: @WouterBeek: Please note that many organizations like  W3C or The Open Group are approved PAS Submitters to ISO/IEC JTC1. So they are preparing documents, but ISO publishes them. So the same procedures apply to get those standards.