# delay execution in prolog?

Tags: prolog

How would I go about delaying execution in prolog?
I can do `threadDelay ms` in Haskell to delay it by `ms` milliseconds. Is there any way to do this in prolog?
I mean I could probably just do a bunch of empty queries like

```
delay(0).
delay(X) :- delay(Y), Y is X - 1.
```

but that seems like a stupid and wrong idea.

EDIT:

Apparently there's `sleep/1`.
However, when I do something like

```
delayText([H|T]) :- put_char(H), sleep(0.1), delayText(T).
delayText([]).
```

, sleep will be executed first (so it will sleep for .5 seconds when querying `delayText("Hello").` or something) and then it will display all the text at once? How do I prevent this?

Comment: In SWI, [`sleep/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sleep/1).

Comment: @DanielLyons thank you!!! is there a standard for this though?

Comment: @DanielLyons edited the post w/ another question

Comment: Change to `put_char(H), flush_output, sleep(0.1), ...`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914155/a-searchable-prolog-language-description-online/10914371#10914371

Comment: I don't know what you want to do, but with SWI-Prolog you can use XPCE and its timers, they don't freeze Prolog and they are very powerful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to formalize my answer, in SWI-Prolog you can use [`sleep/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sleep/1) to delay the process. I don't see an ISO predicate [in this list](http://www.univ-orleans.fr/lifo/software/stdprolog/bips.html) and I wouldn't expect one, since the standard doesn't really specify much about threading or other low-level OS concerns.

To fix `delayText/1` you just need to add in `flush_output`. This is essentially the same as `hFlush stdout` in Haskell, but you can also change the flush mode of the output stream in Haskell with `hSetBuffering`. The SWI version of [`open/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%274.16%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/IO.html%27%29%29) supports a `buffer` option, but it mentions that this is not ISO, so there probably isn't an ISO way to cause flush to automatically happen or make the output unbuffered, though hopefully somebody with more experience with the standard will come along and correct me if I'm wrong.

The corrected code looks like this:

```
delayText([H|T]) :- put_char(H), flush_output, sleep(0.1), delayText(T).
delayText([]).
```

I'd probably write it like this though:

```
delay_put_char(X) :- put_char(X), flush_output, sleep(0.1).
delayText(X) :- maplist(delay_put_char, X).
```

Comment: The list you refer to is outdated. [This one is current](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914155/a-searchable-prolog-language-description-online/10914371#10914371).

Comment: Would it have killed you to link to [the actual list](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#status_quo) rather than your answer?

Answer (score 0):

In Ciao Prolog the same is called `pause/1`. And there is a draft
standard for threads which suggests a `thread_sleep/1` predicate:

> **3.2.11 thread_sleep/1**
> thread sleep(Seconds) suspends the current threads execution until Seconds
> seconds elapsed. When the number of seconds is zero or a negative value, the
> call succeeds and returns immediately.
> https://logtalk.org/plstd/threads.pdf

But as long as there is no PEP or somesuch Prolog systems might
do it differently. For example in this realization the argument
is in milliseconds:

```html
<h1>Example 63: Sleepy Hello</h1>
<script src="https://www.rubycap.ch/rscsrv/dogelog.js"></script>
<script type="application/x-dogelog">
:- write('Hello '), flush_output,
   sleep(1000),
   write('World!'), nl.
</script>
```